# Gradle war plugin : exclude

Tags: gradle, war

I have some difficulties in understanding following built.gradle script

```
war {

    archiveName = 'myapps.war'

    from ( 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/struts' ) {
        exclude '**/struts.properties'
        into 'WEB-INF/classes'
    }

    exclude 'WEB-INF/properties'
    exclude 'WEB-INF/struts'

}
```

After simple look , we can say that do not add struts.properites in generated war. Then what is meaning of exclude properties and struts directory in subsequent lines?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be so: the first, is to copy everything from **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/struts** into **WEB-INF/classes** of artifact, but exclude while copying any struts.properties files. And the second is to exlude from artifact 2 folders **WEB-INF/properties** and **WEB-INF/struts** (as for **WEB-INF/struts**, it's content is already copied to **WEB-INF/classes**)

Comment: Sorry but what is artifact 1 and artifact 2? Is it preparing archive or artifact?

Comment: I mean, an artifact is a war-archive you get after war-task execution. So both artifacts can be replaced with archive word in my answer. Artifact is something you get after task execution, in this case it's a war-archive.